# Find list of items in XML data file based on multiple parent/grandparent element and attribute values and sibling element and attribute values

Tags: xml, vba, xpath

I am trying to filter XML data from a retail POS data file based on multiple conditions.  I have searched for hours, taken a course in XML on SkillShare, purchased a reference book and consulted many friends but have not found what I am looking for.  I am using Excel VBA because it makes it easy for me to place the data where I want it, generate .pdf reports and e-mail them out to list of recipients.  I launch the workbook through a scheduled task, then the workbook.open event runs my code, saves the updated workbook and exits.

my XML data looks like this:
I am included only 1 Transaction element, each data file I am using has between 500 and 1100 Transaction elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- TLD Generator V1.28c -->
<POSLog xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" xmlns:ns1="http://xyz.yum.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ ../XSD/POSLogForFoodserviceV3.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xyz="YUMArtsExtensions">
  <Transaction MajorVersion="3" MinorVersion="0" FixVersion="0" TrainingModeFlag="false">
    <RetailStoreID>026087</RetailStoreID>
    <OrganizationHierarchy Level="OperatingCompany">NMBR</OrganizationHierarchy>
    <OrganizationHierarchy Level="Division">TBC</OrganizationHierarchy>
    <OrganizationHierarchy Level="Concept">TBC</OrganizationHierarchy>
    <WorkstationID>4</WorkstationID>
    <SequenceNumber>375269</SequenceNumber>
    <BusinessDayDate>2019-11-26</BusinessDayDate>
    <BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T12:22:37</BeginDateTime>
    <EndDateTime>2019-11-26T12:27:33</EndDateTime>
    <OperatorID OperatorType="Cashier" OperatorName="RIVERA, YAZMIN">71</OperatorID>
    <TrailerText>
      <Text>
      </Text>
    </TrailerText>
    <ReceiptDateTime>2019-11-26T12:23:21</ReceiptDateTime>
    <RetailTransaction TransactionStatus="Finished">
      <SpecialOrderNumber>
      </SpecialOrderNumber>
      <PriceDerivationResult DiscountBenefit="Manager">
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
        <Percent Action="Subtract">100.00</Percent>
        <PriceDerivationRule>
          <PriceDerivationRuleID>100% Manager Disc.</PriceDerivationRuleID>
          <Amount Action="Subtract">13.48</Amount>
        </PriceDerivationRule>
        <ReasonCode>FIXED DISCOUNT</ReasonCode>
        <OperatorBypassApproval>
          <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
          <ApproverID>71</ApproverID>
        </OperatorBypassApproval>
      </PriceDerivationResult>
      <LineItem CancelFlag="false" VoidFlag="false">
        <!-- 1 Beef Taco Salad -->
        <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
        <Sale>
          <POSIdentity>
            <POSItemID>SLBFFS</POSItemID>
          </POSIdentity>
          <RegularSalesUnitPrice>5.99</RegularSalesUnitPrice>
          <ActualSalesUnitPrice>5.99</ActualSalesUnitPrice>
          <ExtendedAmount>5.99</ExtendedAmount>
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          <Item Action="Add">
            <POSIdentity>
              <POSItemID>BBBF</POSItemID>
            </POSIdentity>
            <RegularSalesUnitPrice>0.00</RegularSalesUnitPrice>
            <ActualSalesUnitPrice>0.00</ActualSalesUnitPrice>
            <ExtendedAmount>0.00</ExtendedAmount>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          </Item>
          <Item Action="Add">
            <POSIdentity>
              <POSItemID>GUAC</POSItemID>
            </POSIdentity>
            <RegularSalesUnitPrice>0.50</RegularSalesUnitPrice>
            <ActualSalesUnitPrice>0.50</ActualSalesUnitPrice>
            <ExtendedAmount>0.50</ExtendedAmount>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          </Item>
          <Item Action="Add">
            <POSIdentity>
              <POSItemID>EXLET</POSItemID>
            </POSIdentity>
            <RegularSalesUnitPrice>0.25</RegularSalesUnitPrice>
            <ActualSalesUnitPrice>0.25</ActualSalesUnitPrice>
            <ExtendedAmount>0.25</ExtendedAmount>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <Modification Action="SpecialInstructions">
              <Name>Extra</Name>
            </Modification>
          </Item>
        </Sale>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem CancelFlag="false" VoidFlag="false">
        <!-- 1 Beef Taco Salad -->
        <SequenceNumber>7</SequenceNumber>
        <Sale>
          <POSIdentity>
            <POSItemID>SLBFFS</POSItemID>
          </POSIdentity>
          <RegularSalesUnitPrice>5.99</RegularSalesUnitPrice>
          <ActualSalesUnitPrice>5.99</ActualSalesUnitPrice>
          <ExtendedAmount>5.99</ExtendedAmount>
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          <Item Action="Add">
            <POSIdentity>
              <POSItemID>GUAC</POSItemID>
            </POSIdentity>
            <RegularSalesUnitPrice>0.50</RegularSalesUnitPrice>
            <ActualSalesUnitPrice>0.50</ActualSalesUnitPrice>
            <ExtendedAmount>0.50</ExtendedAmount>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          </Item>
          <Item Action="Add">
            <POSIdentity>
              <POSItemID>EXLET</POSItemID>
            </POSIdentity>
            <RegularSalesUnitPrice>0.25</RegularSalesUnitPrice>
            <ActualSalesUnitPrice>0.25</ActualSalesUnitPrice>
            <ExtendedAmount>0.25</ExtendedAmount>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <Modification Action="SpecialInstructions">
              <Name>Extra</Name>
            </Modification>
          </Item>
        </Sale>
      </LineItem>
      <!-- SOS -->
      <LineItem>
        <SequenceNumber>11</SequenceNumber>
        <xyz:YUMBOHTransactionExtensions ReportingPerspectiveType="Actual">
          <xyz:SpeedOfService>
            <xyz:OrderSpeedOfService>
              <xyz:OperatorID>71</xyz:OperatorID>
              <xyz:OrderCount>
                <xyz:Type>DriveThru</xyz:Type>
                <xyz:Count>9</xyz:Count>
              </xyz:OrderCount>
              <xyz:SOSTransaction TransactionType="DriveThru">
                <xyz:BusinessDate>2019-11-26</xyz:BusinessDate>
                <xyz:DayPart>2019-11-26</xyz:DayPart>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Cashed Out">1</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T12:22:37</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T12:23:21</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>44</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Kitchen" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Preped Time">2</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T12:23:21</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T12:27:41</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>260</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Total Time">3</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T12:22:37</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T12:27:41</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>304</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="First Item Time">4</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T12:22:37</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T12:22:37</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Stored Order Time">5</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T12:23:21</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T12:23:21</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Recalled Order Time">6</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T12:25:13</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T12:25:13</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Amount Tender Time">7</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T12:27:33</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T12:27:33</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Served Order Time">8</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T12:27:41</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T12:27:41</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Totaled Time">9</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T12:23:21</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T12:23:21</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Checkin Time">10</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
              </xyz:SOSTransaction>
            </xyz:OrderSpeedOfService>
          </xyz:SpeedOfService>
        </xyz:YUMBOHTransactionExtensions>
      </LineItem>
      <Total TotalType="TransactionGrossAmount">13.48</Total>
      <Total TotalType="TransactionNetAmount">0.00</Total>
      <Total TotalType="TransactionTaxAmount">0.00</Total>
      <Total TotalType="TransactionNonSalesAmount">13.48</Total>
      <Total TotalType="X:TransactionPromoAmount">0.00</Total>
      <Customer>
        <CustomerID>
        </CustomerID>
        <CustomerName>
          <FullName>
          </FullName>
        </CustomerName>
      </Customer>
      <Foodservice DestinationType="DriveThru">
      </Foodservice>
    </RetailTransaction>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction MajorVersion="3" MinorVersion="0" FixVersion="0" TrainingModeFlag="false">
    <RetailStoreID>026087</RetailStoreID>
    <OrganizationHierarchy Level="OperatingCompany">NMBR</OrganizationHierarchy>
    <OrganizationHierarchy Level="Division">TBC</OrganizationHierarchy>
    <OrganizationHierarchy Level="Concept">TBC</OrganizationHierarchy>
    <WorkstationID>3</WorkstationID>
    <SequenceNumber>375367</SequenceNumber>
    <BusinessDayDate>2019-11-26</BusinessDayDate>
    <BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:48</BeginDateTime>
    <EndDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:54</EndDateTime>
    <OperatorID OperatorType="Server">99999</OperatorID>
    <TrailerText>
      <Text>
      </Text>
    </TrailerText>
    <ReceiptDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:54</ReceiptDateTime>
    <RetailTransaction TransactionStatus="Canceled">
      <SpecialOrderNumber>
      </SpecialOrderNumber>
      <!-- Before -->
      <LineItem CancelFlag="true" VoidFlag="false">
        <!-- 3 Beef Crunchy Taco -->
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
        <Sale>
          <POSIdentity>
            <POSItemID>T-BF</POSItemID>
          </POSIdentity>
          <Description>Before</Description>
          <RegularSalesUnitPrice>1.59</RegularSalesUnitPrice>
          <ActualSalesUnitPrice>1.59</ActualSalesUnitPrice>
          <ExtendedAmount>4.77</ExtendedAmount>
          <Quantity>3</Quantity>
        </Sale>
      </LineItem>
      <!-- SOS -->
      <LineItem>
        <SequenceNumber>3</SequenceNumber>
        <xyz:YUMBOHTransactionExtensions ReportingPerspectiveType="Actual">
          <xyz:SpeedOfService>
            <xyz:OrderSpeedOfService>
              <xyz:OperatorID>0</xyz:OperatorID>
              <xyz:OrderCount>
                <xyz:Type>DriveThru</xyz:Type>
                <xyz:Count>1</xyz:Count>
              </xyz:OrderCount>
              <xyz:SOSTransaction TransactionType="DriveThru">
                <xyz:BusinessDate>2019-11-26</xyz:BusinessDate>
                <xyz:DayPart>2019-11-26</xyz:DayPart>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Cashed Out">1</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:48</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:54</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>6</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Kitchen" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Preped Time">2</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:54</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Total Time">3</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:48</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="First Item Time">4</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:48</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:48</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Stored Order Time">5</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:54</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:54</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Recalled Order Time">6</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Amount Tender Time">7</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:54</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:54</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Served Order Time">8</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Totaled Time">9</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:54</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T16:05:54</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Checkin Time">10</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
              </xyz:SOSTransaction>
            </xyz:OrderSpeedOfService>
          </xyz:SpeedOfService>
        </xyz:YUMBOHTransactionExtensions>
      </LineItem>
      <Total TotalType="TransactionGrossAmount">0.00</Total>
      <Total TotalType="TransactionNetAmount">0.00</Total>
      <Total TotalType="TransactionTaxAmount">0.00</Total>
      <Total TotalType="TransactionNonSalesAmount">0.00</Total>
      <Total TotalType="X:TransactionPromoAmount">0.00</Total>
      <Customer>
        <CustomerID>
        </CustomerID>
        <CustomerName>
          <FullName>
          </FullName>
        </CustomerName>
      </Customer>
      <Foodservice DestinationType="DriveThru">
      </Foodservice>
    </RetailTransaction>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction MajorVersion="3" MinorVersion="0" FixVersion="0" TrainingModeFlag="false">
    <RetailStoreID>026087</RetailStoreID>
    <OrganizationHierarchy Level="OperatingCompany">NMBR</OrganizationHierarchy>
    <OrganizationHierarchy Level="Division">TBC</OrganizationHierarchy>
    <OrganizationHierarchy Level="Concept">TBC</OrganizationHierarchy>
    <WorkstationID>3</WorkstationID>
    <SequenceNumber>375474</SequenceNumber>
    <BusinessDayDate>2019-11-26</BusinessDayDate>
    <BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T19:53:36</BeginDateTime>
    <EndDateTime>2019-11-26T19:54:03</EndDateTime>
    <OperatorID OperatorType="Server">99999</OperatorID>
    <TrailerText>
      <Text>
      </Text>
    </TrailerText>
    <ReceiptDateTime>2019-11-26T19:54:03</ReceiptDateTime>
    <RetailTransaction TransactionStatus="Canceled">
      <SpecialOrderNumber>
      </SpecialOrderNumber>
      <!-- Before -->
      <LineItem CancelFlag="true" VoidFlag="false">
        <!-- 1 Crunchwrap Supreme -->
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
        <Sale>
          <POSIdentity>
            <POSItemID>CR-WRP</POSItemID>
          </POSIdentity>
          <Description>Before</Description>
          <RegularSalesUnitPrice>4.19</RegularSalesUnitPrice>
          <ActualSalesUnitPrice>4.19</ActualSalesUnitPrice>
          <ExtendedAmount>4.19</ExtendedAmount>
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        </Sale>
      </LineItem>
      <!-- SOS -->
      <LineItem>
        <SequenceNumber>3</SequenceNumber>
        <xyz:YUMBOHTransactionExtensions ReportingPerspectiveType="Actual">
          <xyz:SpeedOfService>
            <xyz:OrderSpeedOfService>
              <xyz:OperatorID>0</xyz:OperatorID>
              <xyz:OrderCount>
                <xyz:Type>DriveThru</xyz:Type>
                <xyz:Count>1</xyz:Count>
              </xyz:OrderCount>
              <xyz:SOSTransaction TransactionType="DriveThru">
                <xyz:BusinessDate>2019-11-26</xyz:BusinessDate>
                <xyz:DayPart>2019-11-26</xyz:DayPart>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Cashed Out">1</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T19:53:36</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T19:54:03</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>27</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Kitchen" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Preped Time">2</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T19:54:03</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Total Time">3</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T19:53:36</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="First Item Time">4</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T19:53:36</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T19:53:36</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Stored Order Time">5</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T19:54:03</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T19:54:03</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Recalled Order Time">6</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Amount Tender Time">7</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T19:54:03</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T19:54:03</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Served Order Time">8</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Totaled Time">9</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>2019-11-26T19:54:03</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>2019-11-26T19:54:03</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
                <xyz:Event EventType="Order" Location="A">
                  <xyz:EventID EventName="Order Checkin Time">10</xyz:EventID>
                  <xyz:BeginDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:BeginDateTime>
                  <xyz:EndDateTime>1899-12-30T00:00:00</xyz:EndDateTime>
                  <xyz:DurationSeconds>0</xyz:DurationSeconds>
                </xyz:Event>
              </xyz:SOSTransaction>
            </xyz:OrderSpeedOfService>
          </xyz:SpeedOfService>
        </xyz:YUMBOHTransactionExtensions>
      </LineItem>
      <Total TotalType="TransactionGrossAmount">0.00</Total>
      <Total TotalType="TransactionNetAmount">0.00</Total>
      <Total TotalType="TransactionTaxAmount">0.00</Total>
      <Total TotalType="TransactionNonSalesAmount">0.00</Total>
      <Total TotalType="X:TransactionPromoAmount">0.00</Total>
      <Customer>
        <CustomerID>
        </CustomerID>
        <CustomerName>
          <FullName>
          </FullName>
        </CustomerName>
      </Customer>
      <Foodservice DestinationType="DriveThru">
      </Foodservice>
    </RetailTransaction>
  </Transaction>
</POSLog>
```

Currently I am able to extract all the items and quantity of items from the list of total items by looping through everything to find if it matches the specific items I am looking for.  I am adding some up and subtracting some based on the VoidFlag attribute.  Here are the xPath statements i am using to get some information.

```
Set itmSold = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("//LineItem[@CancelFlag='false' and @VoidFlag='false']/Sale/POSIdentity/POSItemID/text()")
Set itmSoldQTY = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("//LineItem[@CancelFlag='false' and @VoidFlag='false']/Sale/Quantity/text()")

Set itmMinus = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("/POSLog/Transaction/RetailTransaction/LineItem[@CancelFlag='false' and @VoidFlag='false']/Sale/Combo/Member/Sale/Item[@Action='Subtract']/POSIdentity/POSItemID/text()")
Set itmMinusQTY = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("/POSLog/Transaction/RetailTransaction/LineItem[@CancelFlag='false' and @VoidFlag='false']/Sale/Combo/Member/Sale/Item[@Action='Subtract']/Quantity/text()")
Set itmMod = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("/POSLog/Transaction/RetailTransaction/LineItem[@CancelFlag='false' and @VoidFlag='false']/Sale/Item[@Action='Add']/POSIdentity/POSItemID/text()")
Set itmModQTY = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("/POSLog/Transaction/RetailTransaction/LineItem[@CancelFlag='false' and @VoidFlag='false']/Sale/Item[@Action='Add']/Quantity/text()")
Set itmCombo = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("/POSLog/Transaction/RetailTransaction/LineItem[@CancelFlag='false' and @VoidFlag='false']/Sale/Combo/Member/Sale/Item[@Action='Add']/POSIdentity/POSItemID/text()")
Set itmComboQTY = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("/POSLog/Transaction/RetailTransaction/LineItem[@CancelFlag='false' and @VoidFlag='false']/Sale/Combo/Member/Sale/Item[@Action='Add']/Quantity/text()")
```

I would like to separate my data based on what time of day.  Count total # of Transaction elements with the RetailTransaction TransactionStatus=Finished between 5am and 11am, 11am and 2pm, 2pm and 5pm etc...
using the times in the Transaction/ReceiptDateTime sibling of the /Transaction/RetailTransaction element.
Listing only 1 Transaction here, I recognize that my multiple SelectNode statements may not all apply to this specific Transaction element.  I would also like to not count anything if the //Transaction/RetailTransaction/PriceDerivationResult element exists at all, if there is no price adjustment action to the transaction, this element is not present.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.  I recognize that This is more complex than most XML data structures and that I'm a little crazy trying to learn XML with this being my first data file.  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you please post valid xml. Add the appropriate closing entities to make it valid.

Comment: You are selecting the "fields" of your "record" in parallel. That will only work if the document is guaranteed to be normalized (all "fields" exist and have data). I think it would be better to follow this flow: group Transaction elements by time, for each transaction in the group generate the record, manage cases where data is not present.

Comment: Using this statement
`set RCPTTimes = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("/POSLog/Transaction/ReceiptDateTime/text()")`
I am able to get an array with all the specific string values of the ReceiptDateTime elements.  Using the values of that array I would like to filter the other elements using something like;
`oxmlfile.SelectNodes ("/POSLog/Transaction[ReceiptDateTime=" & RCPTTimes(1) & "']/RetailTransaction/LineItem[@CancelFlag='false' and @VoidFlag='false']/Sale/POSIdentity/POSItemID/text()")`
Where RCPTTimes(1) = 2019-11-26T12:23:21

Comment: I'm having trouble getting correct RCPTTimes list as I need to only get the ReceiptDateTime/text() IF... the sibling element RetailTransaction has the attribute TransactionStatus="Finished"
Any Help filtering would be GREATLY appreciated.
I tried
`RCPTTimes = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("/POSLog/Transaction/RetailTransaction[@TransactionStatus='Finished'][previous-sibling]/ReceiptDateTime/text()")`

Comment: @QHarr I have updated the XML as requested.  Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.  I now have included 3 Transaction Elements to give a fuller look of what I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

By bracketing multiple elements before "/", I filter by multiple siblings.

`Set RCPTTimes = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("/POSLog/Transaction[RetailTransaction[@TransactionStatus='Finished']][WorkstationID/text()='4']/ReceiptDateTime/text()")`
This lists all transactions times on Workstation 4
Using an array DD = time

`Set ITEMSold = oxmlfile.SelectNodes("/POSLog/Transaction[RetailTransaction[@TransactionStatus='Finished']][WorkstationID/text()='4'][ReceiptDateTime='" & dd(1) & "']//RetailTransaction/LineItem[@CancelFlag='false' and @VoidFlag='false']/Sale/POSIdentity/POSItemID/text()")`

I loop through the number of values in the array to find the number of items sold and can isolate not just by time of day, but also by Workstation ID.